# Ajax radio button validation

Tags: validation, radio-button

i have a problem making ajax radio validation, what i need is: i have 4 options, each option has 2(left-side and right-side) selections. no options must have the same selection(left or right). the problem is: you must not select (left and right) in the same option, if you click next it will prompt you with an alert error. i linked an image to better understand what im saying.

http://i176.photobucket.com/albums/w162/jeffprado/1.png~original

Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach($results as $result):?>
        <?php 
        if($i==1){?>         
            <div id="question<?php echo $i;?>" class="cont">
                <?php echo $result['Q1'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M1" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M1" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L1" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L1" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q2'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M2" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M2" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L2" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L2" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q3'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M3" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M3" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L3" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L3" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q4'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M4" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M4" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L4" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L4" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>
            </div><?php
        }
        elseif($i<1 || $i<$rows){?>

            <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                <?php echo $result['Q1'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M1" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M1" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L1" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L1" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q2'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M2" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M2" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L2" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L2" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q3'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M3" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M3" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L3" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L3" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q4'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M4" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M4" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L4" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L4" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>

                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Next</button>
            </div><?php 
        }
        elseif($i==$rows){?>
            <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                <?php echo $result['Q1'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M1" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M1" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L1" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L1" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q2'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M2" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M2" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L2" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L2" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q3'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M3" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M3" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L3" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L3" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $result['Q4'];?>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M4" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M4" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>M"/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L4" id="Q<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L4" name="<?php echo $result['ID'];?>L"/>
                <br/>

                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>
            </div><?php 
        } $i++;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

and here is the ajax script(maybe it will help too):

```
<script>
    $('.cont').addClass('hide');
    count=$('.questions').length;
    $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

    $(document).on('click','.next',function(){
        last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
        nex=last+1;
        $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

        $('#question'+nex).removeClass('hide');
    });

    $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
        last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
        pre=last-1;
        $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

        $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("form").submit();
    }, 60000);
</script>
```